# How to add php to custom link in the nav menu?

Tags: menus, buddypress

I simply want to add some php in as a custom link in the wordpress menu section.  The code I want to use is `<?php bp_loggedin_user_domain(); ?>` which will generate that logged in user's buddypress profile page url.  However, when I paste that in as a custom links, wp removes the opening and closing tags and removes all the white space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu' ) );
} else {
     wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-out-menu' ) );
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is another try, same theory but different execution:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{ 
    // Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
    function new_nav_menu_items($items) 
    {
        $homelink = '&lt;li class=&quot;home&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;' . bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '&quot;&gt;' . __('Profile') . '&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;';
        $items = $homelink . $items;
        return $items;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items' );
}
```

Comment: no I don't want different menus if user logged in or out, I want to generate the custom link that the function bp_loggedin_user_domain() outputs.

Comment: Please check if the edit works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BP Menus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-profile-menu/) plugin. It will add Buddypress menu items to Wordpress Menus and enable you to customize the menu from the dashboard.